# Unity networking server and client communication problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is my first multiplayer game and I wonder how can I make server and client communicate. I have tried this code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerPrefabScript : NetworkBehaviour
{
public bool isHostPlayer;
public static string PlayerName;
public int PlayerScore;
private bool updateNames = true;

void Start()
{
    LoadData();
 
    if (!isServer)
    {
        Debug.Log("Host");
        CmdSendInfo(PlayerName, PlayerScore);
    }
    else if(isServer)
    {
        Debug.Log("Server");
        transform.name = PlayerName;
    }
}

void Update()
{
  
}

[Command]
public void CmdSendInfo(string name, int points)
{
    RpcUpdateInfo(name, points);
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcUpdateInfo(string name, int points)
{
    transform.name = name;
}

public void SaveData()
{
    SaveSystem.SaveData();
}

public void LoadData()
{
    PlayerData data = SaveSystem.LoadData();

    PlayerName = data.PlayerName;
}
```

}

And whenever I build the project and connect via phone to unity builder it always on phone as a client debugs "Host" 2 times and on unity builder as server "Server" 2 times. For now I just want to be able to change players names which they can pick at the start but now it only changes clients name how can I achieve that server will change its name as well?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there are three points:

1. Afaik the `RPC` is only executed on the clients but not the Host itself (might be wrong on that one though)

   => You should do the same change also inside the CMD
2. `PlayerName` should probably rather **not** be `static` so that only the own player object actually performs the loading and only it uses it.

   => You should check if you are `isLocalPlayer` and only do the loading for this one instance
3. A problem remain players that connect later

   => You should make usage of `SyncVar` in order to always pass the data down from the host to all clients, also later connected ones.

   => You actually wouldn't need the RPC

So maybe something like

```
public string PlayerName;
public int PlayerScore;

[SyncVar(hook = nameof(OnRemoteChangedName))] public string SyncedPlayerName;
[SyncVar(hook = nameof(OnRemoteChangedPoints))] public int SyncedPlayerScore;

void Start()
{
   // Important: Check if this is even your own player 
   // we don't want to set the data for the other players
   if(isLocalPlayer)
   {
       LoadData();
 
       name = PlayerName;

       if (!isServer)
       {
           Debug.Log("Client");
           // Tell the server and other clients our name
           CmdSendInfo(PlayerName, PlayerScore);
       }
       else 
       {
           Debug.Log("Server");
           
           // Tell all clients our values even later connected ones
           SyncedPlayerName = name;
           SyncedPlayerScore = PlayerScore;
       }
    }
}

[Command]
public void CmdSendInfo(string newName, int points)
{
    name = newName;
    PlayerName = newName;
    PlayerScore = points;

    // By setting these the values are automatically synced down to all clients
    // even to those that connect later
    SyncedPlayerName = newName;
    SyncedPlayerScore = points;
}

// Will be executed on the client when the host changes the value of SyncedPlayerName
private void OnRemoteChangedName(string newName)
{
    PlayerName = newName;
    name = newName;
}

// Will be executed on the client when the host changes the PlayerScore
private void OnRemoteChangedPoints(int newPoints)
{
    PlayerScore = newPoints;
}
```

Comment: On server it displays the names correctly but not on client.. I just get an error saying "Trying to send command for object without authority"

Comment: @bluxmoon11998 Updated the answer .. UNet is a while ago for me ^^ I think it should do it now

Comment: Still not updating on the client.. I still get the previus mentioned error otherwise everything works like it did before.

Comment: @bluxmoon11998 I think I forgot to also update the name in `Start` so this should work now. I don't really see where the error should come from though ... if this is your player object then both `isLocalPlayer` and `hasAuthority` should be true ... Maybe the client may not assign the `SyncVar` fields though .. removed that now

Comment: The error is gone but it still doesn't update on client.. I watched a tutorial and my code I pasted on top is from that tutorial and he said that you need to call CMD and in that CMD function them RPC so client send to server and then server back to clients.. Maybe here is the problem I don't know anymore I tried too many things..